# Cross Domain Image upload Angular+laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5, cors, ng-file-upload

I have been struggling with image upload on server. I am using [ngFileUpload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) on front end. But I always get

"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Angular Code for file Upload :

```
 var uploadFile = function (file) {
      if (file) {

            if (!file.$error) {
              Upload.upload({
                  url: baseUrl+'upload',
                  file: file


              }).progress(function (evt) {
                  var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
                  //console.log(evt.total);
              }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  $timeout(function() {

                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(status);
                      if(status==200)
                        {

                          logo_path = data.logo_path;

                        }

                  });
              });
            }

      }
  };
```

On Laravel i have configured CORS like this :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8001/");

    // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin'
    ];
    if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        $response->header($key, $value);
    return $response;
}
```

The Normal cross domain POST request works fine. i.e $http.post(). I have tried many different variations of headers on angular but none helps. Also the OPTIONS request returns 200 OK but still preflight response failure message is displayed. Can anyone help me with how to further debug this issue?

Comment: Add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to the headers too.

Comment: To request headers? I didn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type'); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
```

in bootstrap/app.php
You may also insert any other header you may need for access control here.