# Angular 4 Access-Control-Allow-Origin error with localhost url

Tags: json, angular, localhost

I'm leaning Angular, trying to use HTTP get to a json file on localhost url http://api.test/work.but I get the error bellow:

Failed to load http://api.test/work: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

by the way I use laravel to generate json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross Domain Image upload Angular+laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34580415/cross-domain-image-upload-angularlaravel)

Comment: What are you using in backend?

Comment: I use Lumen laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that, `http://api.test/work.but` does not allow cross origin request. If this link is hosted by you, you will have to allow cross origin request.
 In your response headers, you will have to send:
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

This means, any body request to your server.

If you want to allow access to specific domains, you can specify them.

Read more abouut `CORS` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: How to specify this thing . My code in angular :

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()

export class WorkService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  private url: string = '//api.test/work';

  getWork() {
    return this.http.get(this.url).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
}

Comment: This has got nothing to do with angular. This needs to be added from your api server. The server should allow you CORS.

Comment: I got it now I was think the problem from angular code
thanks allot

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error; "Failed to load http://web-api_link: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.". I already had CORS installed on my chrome browser. It was on. I clicked on it and checked for "Enable cross-origin resource sharing". I disabled it, and enabled it again. It worked for me!

Answer (score -1):

```js
private callServiceGet(url: string, wC?: boolean): Promise<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(url, { observe: 'response', withCredentials: wC })
      .catch(err => [ err ])
      .map(data => ({ status: data.status, data: data.body }))
      .toPromise();
  }
```

with wC you have credentials to allow localhost too. It's simply a boolean, so set it to true if you want a complete access.

for example you could use it like this:

```js
getJSON(): Promise<any> {
    return this.callServiceGet(`http://api.test/work`, true);
  }
```